# Swift Query String Passing Int As String To Express

Tags: javascript, swift, express

I am having a problem passing a query string from swift to express. I am passing [String: Any] like so:

```
let params = ["id": 1]
```

To a function which is currently doing the following:

```
 postString = ""
 
 for param in params {

     postString += "\(param.key)=\(content)"

     if params.count > 1 && i < params.count {
         postString += "&"
     }
 }

 let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/api?" + postString)

 guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
 
 var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

 let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
```

So when I pass this into express I get all the parameters that Im passing in, however its showing all values as string. This is the request object:

```
  originalUrl: '/api?id=13',
  query: { id: '13' },
```

How can I properly pass an int through the query string? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd recommend using `URLComponent` and `URLQueryItem`s to construct the URL instead of hand-craftig it. Other than that, there's nothing you can do on the client's side, URL query parameters do not carry type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters don't contain type information and are always strings. You will need to `parseInt` on the parameter value (and handle errors appropriately).